# How can I export Visual Studio shortkeys (Keymap) to IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: visual-studio, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

It's a long time that I use VS and I have fully customized its environment. Now I have to use IntelliJ. It's completely unfamiliar for me. I want to export VS short keys to IntelliJ. Is there any way to do that? I'd appreciate if someone can help me.

I use Visual Studio 2015 Ultimate and IntelliJ IDEA 15 Ultimate.
I use Resharper in Visual Studio. Does it help?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can go to File | Settings, select the Keymap item in the left part of the dialog, and select "Visual Studio" in the Keymap combo box. This should give you keyboard shortcuts in IntelliJ IDEA that are similar to the default settings in Visual Studio.

[image: IntelliJ IDEA: Settings dialog with Keymap topic selected on the left and Visual Studio keymap selected on the top]

To the right of the Keymap combo box, there is a small gears button that allows you to duplicate a keymap. After duplication, you can change keyboard shortcuts for almost every action and even add more shortcuts than what you get by default. This way, you can even add (most of) your personal customizations from Visual Studio to IntelliJ.

Comment: That's awesome! Thank you!

Comment: Great how only a couple of shortcuts are the same.

Answer (score 3):

File > Settings > Keymap select Visual Studio from dropdown

Answer (score 2):

For now, just install vscode keymap from plugin store:

[image]

And there is a VSCode keymap, many thanks to the uploder!