# Is there a way to import VisualStudio 2017 Keyboard shortcuts to IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I recently started working with IntelliJ, I have worked with visual studio 2017 for over 2 years.
Now I want to set IntelliJ keyboard shortcuts the same as it was in Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I export Visual Studio shortkeys (Keymap) to IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34013518/how-can-i-export-visual-studio-shortkeys-keymap-to-intellij-idea)

Comment: @improbable 
Well, it's a matter of preference.